# How To Turn JS Objects To HTML And Style With CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, css-selectors

I'm learning JSON (or JS Objects) and I'm trying to figure out how to bring said objects into HTML and style them using CSS.

How can I select 'firstName' and 'lastName' objects to style them?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/5bfzo1q2/25/

```js
var data = { "users":[
            {
                "firstName":"Jack",
                "lastName":"Lewis",
                "startDate": {
                    "month":"January",
                    "day":12,
                    "year":2000
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"Raymond",
                "lastName":"Girard",
                "startDate": {
                    "month":"April",
                    "day":28,
                    "year":1994
                }
            },
            {
                "firstName":"Enrique",
                "lastName":"Sosa",
                "startDate": {
                    "month":"October",
                    "day":14,
                    "year":2004
                }
            }
    ]}

    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.users) {
        output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + " &ndash; " + data.users[i].startDate.month + " " + data.users[i].startDate.day + ", " + data.users[i].startDate.year+ "</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";
  
    document.getElementById("writeTo").innerHTML=output;
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body {
    background: MediumTurquoise;
    font: normal 17px/1.8em Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px darkcyan;
    background: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding:20px;
    
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    color: #555;
    list-style:none;
    
}
.firstName :first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="writeTo"></div>
```

Comment: Wrap then in `<span>`s when adding them to the `<li>`, then style them that way.

Comment: You can't do anything to them while they are inside the JS object. You need to output those properties to the DOM.

Comment: JSON (or JS objects, as in this case) cannot be styled with CSS. Only HTML elements can be styled in such a manner. Rewrite the question and title to show only the *final/actual* HTML - and therein the problem will be visible. If the problem is about converting the JSON to appropriate HTML, then ask about that (and remove anything wrt CSS). I recommend using proper DOM manipulation to generate the HTML/content.

Comment: Let me know if the subject and question are any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't select JSON with CSS. It operates on a DOM.

It looks like you aren't trying to though. You just have a text node (which you created using half a dozen strings) in a list item.

Currently you don't have anything that CSS could select (which is mostly limited to elements) that would distinguish between the various bits of data, so you can't.

You need to add additional markup.

e.g.

```
"<li><span class='firstName'>" + data.users[i].firstName + "</span>"
```

I'd strongly suggest building each element at a time and `append`ing them rather then trying to mash up a huge string though.

Comment: Welllll technically you can query JSON with a selector [given an implementation that performs all the necessary mappings](http://jsonselect.org), although obviously the first statement is merely a simplification, as the question is really about transforming data from JSON into DOM elements then styling them with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to wrap the first and last name in another tag and add the css style to the new tag.

```
"<li><span>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + "</span>"
```

and for the css

```
ul li span:first-child {
      font-weight:bold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bfzo1q2/26/